# subquery where condition from different table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

By using **subquery library** function how is it possible to select a record that matches the condition from both tables in subquery...?

Here is the actual **sql query**

```
SELECT *, (SELECT count('report_id') 
           FROM report 
           WHERE report.category = category.cat_id 
                 and report.user_id IN (68, 69, 70)) AS cnt 
FROM (`category`)
```

I need the equivalent in **codeigniter** as:

```
    $this->db->select('*')->from('category');
    $sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('select');
    $sub->select("count('report_id')")->from('report')
        ->where_in(array('user_id'=>(68, 69, 70)));
    $this->subquery->end_subquery('number');
```

In this how can i put my second condition...???

Answer (score 3):

By the way is there a  really need of dependent sub query this will only increase the load and it will be executed for each row in category table,You can write equivalent join query as

```
SELECT c.*, 
COUNT(DISTINCT r.report_id) AS cnt /*you can omit distinct if you have unique report ids  */
FROM `category` c
LEFT JOIN report r ON r.category = c.cat_id AND r.user_id IN (68, 69, 70)
GROUP BY c.cat_id
```

And active record query as

```
$result = $this->db->select('c.*,COUNT(DISTINCT r.report_id) AS cnt ',FALSE)
    ->from('category c')
    ->join('report r','r.category = c.cat_id AND r.user_id IN (68, 69, 70)','LEFT')
    ->group_by('c.cat_id')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

Comment: thanks its works,,, but if there is a situation occurs to do so, how can i put second table field inside where condition

Comment: @rbvishnu you can use `->where('r.column_name',$value)` to apply ny filter ,is that you asked for ?

Comment: I need to include this condition: report.category = category.cat_id

Comment: sorry, what i want is to include the where condition in subquery method using library. How is it possible... if i am preferring first method, anyway i will get the result using join as you mentioned

Comment: @rbvishnu which `subquery library` you are using with CI ? Also i don't have idea using sub queries in active records and also join are more better than sub queries in performance